# 'Need to know the correct English for "snacks served" or "provided"?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

This might be a silly question, but recently I came across in Facebook an event where it was written **snacks will be provided**.

Is it a correct English phrase or it should be like *snacks will be served*?

Comment: *Provided* and *served* have quite different meanings and a simple dictionary would help you understand these terms better.

Comment: Do they convey the same idea?

Comment: Why don't you look them up?

Comment: Well, snacks which are "served" may be placed on plates in their naked state. They're commonly called hors d'oeuvres. You then you help yourself and perhaps put them on a paper plate and take a napkin for wiping your fingers. Sometimes the hors d'oeuvres come with a toothpick stuck into them, which makes eating them a little less messy. As for snacks which are simply "provided," well, they could take the form of, say,  a basket of apples and a basket of wrapped granola bars. Not very classy, but folks appreciate having them available at informal occasions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Snacks will be provided.

That is correct English.

When attending some events, you must take your own snacks with you.

This simply indicates that snacks will be provided *by the organizers*.

It doesn't say anything about how they will be served. It is simply letting you know you don't have to bring any food because they will provide it.

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your stated question, both phrases are grammatically correct and proper English.

As to whether there is a difference, it seems to be a regional variation.  In my mid-west US experience, there is no difference- I would have the same expectation upon arriving at the event no matter what word was used in the invitation.

However, the comments indicate that others might disagree with me.  Perhaps to some "provided" means only that snacks will be on a table and you can take them as you walk by, and "served" means that someone will bring them to you.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically, both are correct. But normally I would take “snacks will be provided” to mean that there will be some stale biscuits on paper plate, while “refreshments will be served” promises at least a reasonable glass of wine.